# Calculate $ \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{2 e^{- i \delta} }{ e^{- i \delta} - M( e^{- i \delta})} d \delta $ when $M(\cdot)$ is a Möbius transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

Let $y \in \mathbb{C}$ with $ \vert y \vert < 1$.
Then it is relatively easy to show that
$$
\int_0^{2 \pi}  \frac{1 - \vert y \vert^2}{\vert e^{-i \delta} - y \vert^2} d \delta = 2 \pi. 
$$
For example one can write
$$
\frac{1 - \vert y \vert^2}{\vert e^{-i \delta} - y \vert^2} = Re \left( \frac{2 w}{w - y} -1 \right) 
$$
with $w = e^{- i \delta} $
and solve that integral using Cauchys integral formula.

Now, if I replace $y$ by a Möbius transformation $M(w) = \frac{aw + b}{cw + d} $. Then I try to calculate the same integral
$$
\int_0^{2 \pi}  \frac{1 - \vert M(\delta) \vert^2}{\vert e^{-i \delta} - M(\delta) \vert^2} d \delta = 2 \pi?? 
$$
and I can use the same trick to try to calculate:

$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{2 w}{w - M(w)} d \delta 
$$
Now, if the Möbius transformation has its two fixed points inside the unit circle then
one can use the Residue theorem to see that indeed on still gets $2 \pi$ (since they are then the poles of the transformation and they add up nicely.

I know that this only depends on $\vert \frac{c}{d} \vert $ whether the roots are inside or outside the the unit circle.

Further, I have the information that $\vert{M(w) \vert} \leq K < 1$ for all $ w$ on the unit circle. So one can also do some tricks using the maximum principle and Rouches theorem. But I cannot rule out that the roots are outside the unit circle.

All I seek is a bound on $\int_0^{2 \pi}  \frac{1 - \vert M(\delta) \vert^2}{\vert e^{-i \delta} - M(\delta) \vert^2} d \delta$ independent of $K$ and of the coefficients in $M$. Is this impossible, any suggestions?